# Wavesurfer.js can't recognize the container of waveform

Tags: angular, wavesurfer.js

I'm using wavesurfer with angular, i tried to put the container of the waveform inside a blocks of html tags with *ngIf and *ngFor, when i ran the project, angular gave me a error message like this "cannot find container element".  What i want to do right now is the way to put the container of waveform inside that block of html codes but still can play the audio. More info ( The blocks of html codes that i mentioned are elements in an audio player like album arts, song's name, artist's name that are rendered by *ngFor of a data list getting data from GET service).

I tried to move the container outside the blocks of code and everything works fine but what i want is to make in run inside these blocks of code

This is the container of wavesurfer :

```
<div id="waveform"></div>
```

This is the blocks of code that i want to surround it :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="playlist">
<div id="waveform"></div>
<div class="coverAll" flexLayout="column">
    <div class="upperPart" flexLayout="row" style="background-image: url(https://images.genius.com/225d8b51efbfa327ed66d35898468855.1000x1000x1.jpg) blur">
        <div class="albumArt" fxFlex="30">
            <img src="https://static.tumblr.com/exbflx8/z13m20ek0/cover.png" alt="Smiley face" height="270px" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="space" fxFlex="2"></div>
        <div class="rightPart" fxFlex="70">
            <div class="songInfo">
                <h1>{{playlist.playlistName}}</h1>
                <ng-container *ngIf="currentSongName">
                    <h4>Now playing : {{currentSongName}}</h4>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            <button (click)="play()">Play</button>
            <img *ngIf="waveform" src={{waveform}}>
            <div class="audioPlayer">
                <audio src="{{currentSongURL}}" controls style="width: 98%">
                </audio>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let song of playlist.songs" class="lowerPart">
        <a style="text-decoration:none">
            <div class="songChoosing" flexLayout=column style="border-bottom-style:inset;">    
                <div class="songMember" flexLayout="row">
                    <a (click)="changeSong(song)">
                        <div class="coverHolder" fxFlex="5">
                            <img src="{{song.songCoverArt}}" alt="Smiley face" height="28" width="35" class="miniCover">
                        </div>
                        <div class="miniSongNameHolder" fxFlex="75">
                            <p class="miniSongName">{{song.songName}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

I'm newbie in angular , i hope u guys can help to overcome this issue ! Tks all !

Comment: Hi, @Thang. Did you try to move `*ngIf` to here `<div class="coverAll" flexLayout="column">`?

Comment: @AmirChristian i tried, i think the problem is that the container cannot play under the *ngIf :((( but what i want to put it is under *ngIf cuz i use *ngIf as a condition to ensure that variable playlist is not undefined :(((

Comment: Can you share your .ts file?